# Playing sound in Matlab at +30dB

Tags: matlab, audio

As far as I know when I load wav files to matlab with command:

`song = wavread('file.wav');`

array song have elements with values from -1 to 1. This file (and hardware) is prepared to be played with 80dB. I need to add +30dB to achieve 110dB.
I do +10dB by multiplying by sqrt(10), so to get +30dB I do:

`song = song*10*sqrt(10);` which is the same as

`song = song*sqrt(10)*sqrt(10)*sqrt(10);`

Now values of array song have much greater values than -1 to 1 and I hear distorted sound.
Is it because of this values greater than <-1,1> or quality of my speakers/headphones?

Comment: Most audio files have very little "headroom", assuming they have been recorded properly, so if you try to make them louder you will just get clipping and distortion.

Comment: Also you may be getting confused about dB. dB is just a *ratio* but it's often used as a ratio relative to some implied reference, e.g. `dB SPL` is commonly used for sound levels and it expresses loudness relative to a reference pressure at 0 dB SPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distortion is because your values are exceeding +/-1. The float values are converted to ADC counts, which are either +/-32768 (for a 16-bit ADC) or +/-8388608 (for a right-justified 24-bit ADC) or +/-2147483648 (for a left-justfied 24-bit ADC). For a 16-bit ADC, this is usually accomplished by an operation like `adcSample = (short int)(32768.0*floatSample);` in C. If `floatSample` is > +1 or < -1 this will cause wraparound in the short int cast, which is the distortion you hear. The cast is necessary because the ADC expects 16-bit digital samples.

You will need to adjust your amplifier/speaker settings to get the sound level you desire.

Conversely, you could create a copy of your file, *lower* it by 30 dB, adjust your amplifier/speakers to play the new file at 80 dB, then play the original file at the same amp/speaker settings. This will cause the original file to be played at 110 dB.

As Paul R noted in his comment, I am guessing here that you are using `dB` as shorthand for `dB SPL` when referring to the actual analog sound level produced by the full signal chain.

Comment: I will try to play original file at 110dB. Thank you.